# What is number of line segments whose vertices are in $S$ and whose length is a positive integer?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, combinations

> Consider a chessboard of size $8$ units $×$ $8$ units (i.e.
>   each small square on the board has a side length of $1$ unit). Let
>   $S$ be the set of all the $81$ vertices of all the squares on the board.
>   What is the number of line segments whose vertices are in $S$,
>   and whose length is a positive integer? (The segments need not
>   be parallel to the sides of the board.)

This problem is from RMO 2017 Maharashtra and Goa Region.
I think I have successfully calculated the number of lines parallel to either of the sides of the chess board.
I found it to be
$$1×9×2+2×9×2+3×9×2+...+8×9×2$$
(Am I right?)
Now, I am ready to count the number of non parallel lines.
I find that there are only two pythagorean triplets-$(3,4)$ and $(8,6)$ up to $8$.
What next? How to proceed?
(Please tell me if I am wrong anywhere)

Comment: Am I wrong anywhere?

Comment: What's wrong with this person https://d24cdstip7q8pz.cloudfront.net/t/t20170803140920/content/common/documents/RMO-2017-maharashtra-goa-solutions.pdf  ?

Comment: Obviously something is wrong, they get same result, but what they wrote has no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did ok for the straight lines

Non-paralels are 3right4up, 3r4d, 4r3u, 4r3d and similar for 6,8

There is 4*6*5+4*3*1

Comment: Yes I also got $5×6×2×2$. Let me check the other.

Comment: Yes I also get $3×2×2×1$

Comment: Please see my comment on the question

Comment: @Amityas that is correct, you see just move vector (3,4) around table, it may be placed on 30 positions. Same for vectors (3,-4),(4,3),(4,-3)

Comment: you mean the PDF's?

Comment: what do you men by 'that'?

Comment: No I ment on your question, I am on phone cannot open this pdf

Comment: THe PDF says-$5 × 8 × 2 × 2$ for $4,2$ and $7 × 3 × 2 × 2$ for $8,6$

Answer (score 4):

To count the line segments parallel to an edge, first you pick a direction, horizontal or vertical, $2$ ways, then you pick a line $9$ ways, then you pick two points on the line $9 \choose 2$ ways.  $2 \cdot 9 \cdot {9 \choose 2}=648$

For line segments not parallel to an edge, they must be the hypotenuse of a pythagorean triangle with sides less than or equal to $8$.  The only ones of those are $3,4,5$ and $6,8,10$.  For $6,8,10$ the $8$ has to be all the way across the board.  There are three of those near each edge and two choices of the third point, so $4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2=24$ but we have counted each one twice as the triangle has two orientations for $12$.  For $3,4,5$ the L of the $3,4$ can go in eight orientations, the $3$ can go in six locations in its row and the $4$ can go in five locations in its row.  $8 \cdot 6 \cdot 5=240$  but again we have counted each one twice, so $120$

The grand total is $648+12+120=780$

Comment: Yes, I got the parallel lines correct.

Comment: I am not able to understand how it is $8×6×5$

Comment: You counted some of them twice

Comment: This is for Ross(my at the rate key is not working!)- I think Djura's ans. is correct

Comment: Please see my comment on the question

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov:  yes, in fact all of the oblique ones.

Comment: Is the PDFcorrect?